# Load balancing Postgresql Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql, pgpool

I have a server (debian 11) on which there is a psql container, with an existing database. My number of customers is increasing day by day, so I plan for the future and want to make my server flexible in order to increase my performance according the number of customers.

I therefore wish, over time to deploy several new machines on which I would deploy other psql containers which will have to work in collaboration (load balacing etc ...)

So I have now deployed a new machine on which I have installed a blank psql container.
What are the steps that I must follow so that this new database is synchronized with my existing database, and can collaborate together?

I have already followed several tutorials found on the web but unfortunately I am a little lost. Some people talk about pgpool-II, others only talk about replication. I tried to do a replication but unfortunately I can't do it in docker

Comment: If you already work with docker (as i understand), why not deploying your application to a Kubernetes cluster, and making an HPA mechanism for load-balancing ?
As i see it, this is the best approach at this case.

Comment: On my main server I don't just have one database I also have many other services running (backend, frontend, sip server, ftp server, push notification server....).
I noticed that the bottleneck of my entire ecosystem is my database, so I would like to increase its performance without affecting all the rest of my infrastructure. That's why I would like to deploy another database on another machine that collaborates with each other to provide better performance.